# VB - Writing to a file, closing and Object existance

Tags: vb.net, object, streamwriter, file-writing

I am writing a program that writes data to a text file at different points in my code, for example in different subroutines, functions or at different parts of subroutines (being scattered around).

First, I `Dim` the file writer:

`Dim CurrentHisWriter As System.IO.StreamWriter`

I tell it where to write to:

`CurrentHisWriter = New System.IO.StreamWriter("C:\ProgramData\Japanese Conjugation Helper\LastSearch.txt")`

Then, I actually write things:

`CurrentHisWriter.Writeline("thing to write")`

The problem is that I have to change to a different subroutine and then keep on writing to a file, so I have to close the writer and then dim another one in another subroutine:

`CurrentHisWriter.Close`

`NewSubroutine()`

[NewSubroutine]:

`Dim CurrentHisWriter As System.IO.StreamWriter`
`CurrentHisWriter = New System.IO.StreamWriter("C:\ProgramData\Japanese Conjugation Helper\LastSearch.txt")`

But then when I do this, I gives me one of a couple errors:

- The program is has an instance of the file running
- Some thing to do with there being no object (I don't remember exactly)

What is a reliable way programming the writing to files without having to worry about closing the writer at every point I change subroutines. I'm not sure about how objects and instances work and so the only thing I can do now is make a catch loop around every single line that uses the "CurrentHisWriter.Writeline" but this isn't really working too.

I know my lack of knowledge in this doesn't help explain, but I tried my best.

Comment: `Using writer as new StreamWriter("Some path") writer.WriteLine("Some Text") End Using`. Maybe make a single method, e.g., `public sub WriteToThatWellKnownFile(stringToWrite as String)` and write to that file using this method only. Unless you have some multi-threading going on, then you have to lock the access to the StreamWriter.

Comment: @Jimi Ok, I think I understand. Thanks

Comment: This looks like just what a logger does. Did you think about using of the well known log libraries available for free?

Answer (score 0):

The naive approach would be like:

```
Sub Main()
  MethodA()
  MethodB()
End Sub

Sub MethodA()
  Log("Starting method A")
End Sub

Sub MethodB()
  Log("Starting method B")
End Sub

Sub Log(message as String)
  System.IO.File.AppendAllText("C:\temp\my.log", message)
End Sub
```

File.AppendAllText is pretty good at closing things off so you can subsequently write to it elsewhere

A better approach would be to have a class whose job it is to build this file, and it builds it all into a stringbuilder and then writes it once. Multiple of your methods use that class, build that file... The class can either implement some timed/periodic dumping of data to disk (if it's like logging, never ending, thousands of events per second.. but then perhaps you'd just use a logging framework rather than reinvent the wheel), or it has a write method that saves the rendering of it to disk

If there is another specialized application of your data at work here, for example if you're generating XML or JSON you should look at specific serialization approaches for those (wheels that have already been invented)

Answer (score 0):

I use

```
FileOpen(1, "file.txt", OpenMode.Append)
```

Now you can write from any other subroutine

```
PrintLine(1, "text to write")
```

Until the file is closed

```
FileClose(1)
```

But maybe you could solve your problem this way:
Define CurrentHisWriter outside of subroutine as
`Private CurrentHisWriter As System.IO.StreamWriter = ...`.
Then you won't have to close and reopen the writer, all your Subs and functions will have access to it.